# android relativelayout: the last viewgroup won't get over the header?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the last viewgroup with ID chats to overlap the previous viewgroups and occupy the whole screen of my phone. With the XML code below I presume it will get what I want. But the codes does not. Please help.

Below is the xml codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.testapp.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bar_img"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_black_24dp"
        android:gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar_title"
        android:text="title"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_frag"
    android:layout_below="@id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chats"
    android:background="#ea2312"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width`enter code here`="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="hello world"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the preview screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z84SL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The "chats" `LinearLayout` **does** fill the whole screen, but the "bar" `LinearLayout` appears on top of it (even though it's defined earlier inside the `RelativeLayout`) because of its `android:elevation` attribute.

To make this stop, either remove the `elevation` attr from the "bar" view, or add a (larger) `elevation` attr to the "chats" view.